# How to check what is my network card on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, wireless

I just installed Ubuntu and Wireless was not working, so I made a question: [Wi-Fi not working on ASUS X75VD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295841/wi-fi-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-asus-x75vd)

I got many answers to give my Network Card, so I made this question.
Please answer quickly!

Comment: The way we classify a thread as "solved" is to click the arrow tick sign next to the answer that answered your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want to give the best output, something like this would be best appreciated.

```
$ lspci | awk '/[Nn]et/ {print $1}' | xargs -i% lspci -ks %
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Or `sudo lshw -c network` but you might want to exclude some of the information (ip/serials/etc) but it might not bother you though.

Answer (score 21):

Run this on a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T):

```
lspci | grep -i net
```

Answer (score 7):

Maybe your interface card has changed from `eth0` to `eth1`. This has happened often with me. To check, type this command:

```
sudo ls /sys/class/net
```